How can I programmatically obtain the PageSpeed Insights report ID using Node.js (without web scraping)?
I’m trying to get the unique report URL (like https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-example-com/djlqz3yt2f) for a PageSpeed Insights analysis programmatically using Node.js. I know it's possible to generate this URL by scraping the web interface, but I'd prefer to avoid that approach.
Is there a Node.js package or API that can directly provide the report ID or the URL for an existing PageSpeed Insights report after running an analysis?
I’m already using the PageSpeed Insights API to get performance metrics, but I can’t find a way to retrieve the report ID or unique URL through the API. I've tried many APIs but none seem to return it.
The reason I want this ID is so that other people can look at the link in the future and read the report easily, without having it load again.
Any suggestions or approaches that would help would be appreciated!
